# NSClassFromString vs. objc_getClass?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

Is there any reason to use `NSClassFromString` instead of `objc_getClass`, assuming that I don't already have an `NSString *` (i.e. just choosing which type of string literal to write)? My assumption is that `NSClassFromString` calls `objc_getClass` anyways, so it's slightly more efficient to use the runtime function.

Answer (score 1):

`NSClassFromString` is a higher-level function than `objc_getClass`, which as you say, is more convenient due to the fact that it takes an `NSString`. So `objc_getClass` should be fine. With that said, if performance is a major concern, Objective-C runtime hackery isn't usually the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are better off optimising for your own usability/readability and using the higher level `NSClassFromString`. The lower level APIs will be more awkward to use (especially from Swift) and will look out of place in amongst all your other app code that's written in Objective-C/Swift.

I wouldn't worry about efficiency too much unless you find you have performance issues and can track it back to using this function (very unlikely).